# Why am I getting errors when I put my views inside sub-folder in CI 2.0+?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, load

I am making a simple application and I am familiar with CodeIgniter 1.7.3, which I didn't have any problems putting sub folders into the application/views folder.

My problem is specifically when I try and load the view, I get the standard CI error message of An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file: usercontentpages/testview.php

However if I move the view file out of the sub folder and place it in the application/views folder the load view command works fine?

I can't find any documentation in the user guide on why this is so?

Here is my Controller:

```
    <?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{

//Controller Constructor
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //Home Page (Default)
    public function index()
    {       
         //Loading a Partial View
         $mContent = $this->load->view('home', '', TRUE); //this works
        //$mContent = $this->load->view('subfolder/home', '', TRUE); //this doesn't work

         $data = array(
             'mainContent' => $mContent,
         );
         //Passing the partial view to the master page
         $this->load->view('usermasterpage', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my Master Page:

```
<?php
//Doctype
echo doctype('html');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()">
    <div id="wrap">

        <!-- Main Content Div -->
        <div id="mainContent">
        <?php 
            /* Every page will have a main content area */
            if(isset($mainContent))
            {
                echo $mainContent;
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And Finally here is the page snippet I'm trying to load:

```
<p>Hi there</p>
```

Comment: What is in your controller calling this view?

Comment: OK, you'll need to show the definition of those constants. And what are in your logs?

Comment: @cwallenpoole, I'm trying to figure out how to turn on logging so I can check it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter will successfully use nested views: I use nested views all the time and I know others who do as well, and it works out of the box. Show some code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have also successfully used nested views, but in CI 1.7.3, I know its possible, I just don't know where my error is coming from?

Comment: You either have a PHP processing error of some kind (given your view content I kind of doubt it), a path error (the file you think you're pointing at is not where you think it should be) or perhaps a permissions error of some kind is preventing the view from being loaded? With what you put down it really should just work.

Comment: It could be a permissions problem, I was having a weird permissions issue earlier and then I chmod'd the folder in order to get past that, and immediately ran against this problem

Comment: Yep it was a folder permissions problem, didn't chmod the sub folders as well.  Thanks Femi!

Comment: Specifically the problem was I created the project as "root" on a different computer, some weird permissions issue -- even when I was logged in as root on my machine, it wasn't working... Moral of the story:  Don't create projects as a "root" user!!!!

Comment: Please help check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360697/link-to-view-inside-subfolder-does-not-display-correctly

Answer (score 1):

The CodeIgniter documentation says precisely that you *can*.

> Your view files can also be stored within sub-folders if you prefer that type of organization. When doing so you will need to include the folder name loading the view. Example:

```
$this->load->view('folder_name/file_name');
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: I already tried looking to the user's guide. saw exactly what you cut and pasted, quadruple checked my code, but nonetheless I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask why your code doesn't work, your question asks why doesn't CI support it. So that's your first problem right there.